# svg.js: horizontally offset newline tspans to create staggered appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg.js

Is there a proper way to horizontally offset tspans in each new line? I want to create a stagger effect, so that all new line is offset the width of the preceding line e.g.:

```
sentence 1
          sentence 2
                    sentence 3 
                              etc
```

I have to following which gives me a text block where all the lines begin at the same x position:

```
let content = SVG('text-box'); // initialize svg element
let sentences = ["sentence 1", "sentence 2", "sentence 3"];

// create a text block
let text_block = content.text(function (add) {
    // create tspans for every sentence
    for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        add.tspan(sentences[i]).newLine(); 
    }
});
```

I know that this easily doable with pure html and css only, but it has to be as svg element, so that I can add horizontal flowing animations later on. All the staggered lines should then flow from right to left.

Comment: when using the newLine command you are basically handing the linemanagement over to svg.js. What you want is using dy to offset your line e.g. `add.tspan(sentences[i]).dy(offset) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a kinda hacky solution (only works with monospace fonts):

Added `<span id="ruler" style="visibility:hidden">x</span>` to my `index.html`

```
let ruler = $('#ruler');
// get pixel length of one char
let char_unit = ruler.width();

let content = SVG('text-box'); // initialize svg element
let sentences = ["sentence 1", "sentence 2", "sentence 3"];

// create a text block
let text_block = content.text(function (add) {
    // create tspans for every sentence
    let sent_offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        add.tspan(sentences[i]).newLine().dx(sent_offset); // added x offset
        // compute offset depending on length of preceding sentence and ruler value
        sent_offset += (sentences[i].length * char_unit); 
    }
});
```

It is not 100% accurate but it serves my purpose good enough. Let me know if someone finds a better (maybe less hacky) solution.